# VBA - Code Error Out at Copy/Paste Portion

Tags: vba

All,

The code is erring out at this portion `X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("A").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("D3")`. Can you advise how this can be resolved? My goal is to take the active sheet and migrate data to an existing saved workbook. The active workbook is different daily so routing it though the file path is not the most supportive option.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Datamove()
    '
    Worksheets.Add().Name = "TEMP"
    Sheets("MCI").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("TEMP").Select
    Sheets("TEMP").Paste

  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$799").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "MC1A", "MC1B", "MC1C", "MC1D", "MC1E", "MC1F", "MC1G", "MC1H", "MC1J", "MC1K", "MC1L", _
        "MC1M", "MC1N", "MC1P", "MC1Q", "MC1R", "MC2A", "MC2B", "MC2C", "MC2D", "MC2E", "MC3A", _
        "MC3C"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$799").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        "Residential"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$799").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="


Dim X As Workbook
Dim Y As Workbook

Set X = ActiveWorkbook
Set Y = Workbooks.Open("insert filepath")

X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("A").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("D3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("R").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("F3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("AU").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("B3")


End Sub
```

Comment: What row in A do you want to copy?

Comment: what is `Set Y = Workbooks.Open("insert filepath")` doing? Do you have a workbook named "insert filepath"? and what's the error description?

Comment: I want the entire column. Would I need to adjust the code to A:A? I removed the file path for the post. The file opens effortlessly. The issue is when attempting to move the data between the two files. It prompts for a debug at the X.Sheets("Temp") portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("A3").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("D3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("R3").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("F3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("AU3").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("B3")
```

Here you can read more for the range object:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you want to copy only the columns, use like this:

```
Columns("A:A").Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

supposing the code down to `Set Y = Workbooks.Open("insert filepath")`
 runs smothlessly, then substitute:

```
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("A").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("D3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("R").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("F3")
X.Sheets("TEMP").Range("AU").Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("B3")
```

with:

```
With X.Sheets("TEMP")
    .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("D3")
    .Range("R1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("F3")
    .Range("AU1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AU").End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Y.Sheets("Text Template").Range("B3")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you the With statement resolved the error. I appreciate the support.